# How to point to particular folder(by default) when i click on browse button of Html file tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I want my browse window pointing to particular folder(for Example D:/Test) by default when i click on browse button while doing file upload.Is there any way to set it using either jQuery or JavaScript?

```
<input type="file" name="myfile" id="myfile"/>
```

[image]

Comment: To put it simply, no.